# Looking for way to easily implement a File/IO-like class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, io

I'd like to implement a file-like class in Ruby (1.9), but don't want to re-implement or decorate every single method that the StringIO and IO classes offer.  Is there a module I can include to help me with that?  I'd like to offer a `read()` method and get a `readLines()` method (that then uses `read()`) for free.

This would be similar to how the Comparable module adds the operators `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, and `>` as long as `<=>` has been implemented.  I look for something like that for files.

If I remember correctly, Java and/or Apache Commons work like this: there are basically just one or two methods, and all the others use them for reading/writing.

I'm implementing a wrapper for writable File and StringIO objects that transparently updates a SHA256 digest on every write.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to inherit from IO, then you're probably going to want to use the methods in Kernel, particularly [open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-open), `gets` and its implementations of `readline` or `readlines`.

You are throwing away a lot of pre-written code that has been debugged though. Personally, I would sub-class IO and alias the "read" and "write"-type routines to some safe name, then create new versions that do the write by calling the original, then update the SHA256.

Comment: Inheriting from IO and StringIO is fine for me, as long as I know which methods I have to overwrite to make the result non-seekable and every string `write` receives go through the `SHA256#update` method.  I just don't want to have to decorate every single method myself.

Comment: Using the Kernel methods is not an option, since those will use global variables depending on their (lack of) arguments.

Answer (score 2):

As you already say that you are implementing "wrapper classes", I would recommend using the [Decorator Pattern](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/decorator-pattern-with-ruby-in-8-lines.html).

Ruby allows you several ways to implement it, it's simple and allows you exactly what you want: If for example implementing the pattern using `method_missing`, you would only implement the write methods that you need for the digest calculation. In the implementation, delegate the write to the decorated object, and also update your SHA256 Digest instance with the String that is written.

Comment: I know the pattern, and I'd like to avoid having to decorate ~10 methods.  Also, obviously I can't "do my SHA256 on the return value" as e.g. the `IO#write` method will happily return "the number of bytes written", not the original string.  So -1 for now for that part of your answer, maybe you can improve it or just remove that incorrect part.

Comment: That's the whole point of the decorator pattern in Ruby - you don't have to decorate all methods, if you use e.g. an implementation with 'method_missing'. Just implement the ones where you need to update the digest. I meant return value when reading from the IO because you were talking about reading in the beginning. I'll correct that part.

Comment: Undid -1.  I'm still not very happy about it, because as I see it, I get to decorate `<<`, `putc`, `puts`, `syswrite`, and `write`, and some of them differ in their argument expectations.  I can't just assume it's a String I'm getting and be done with `def method_missing m,*a ; @sha << a[0] ; @dec.send m, *a ; end`.  Or can I?

Comment: Especially tricky: `printf`.  At least that one would need its own proxy / decorator method.

Comment: And just imagine the tons of writing methods that Ruby 1.9.7 would add for all file-like classes.  I'd rather not keep hunting for future API additions here.  Not that this is likely, but still.